# Adding column of gene symbol in a count matrix with ensemble ID names Seurat object .RDS file

Tags: seurat

I am trying to carry out a single-cell analysis in which I started with a `.RDS` file. I was developing the workflow but I have stopped in the Quality control, because I need to add de "percent.mt" column in the count matrix of the dataset. I was trying but I discovered that the genes was named by ENSEMBLE ID nomenclature, and I need it in genesymbol. While trying to add that column, I found an error in the last step of it. I will show my script in case somebody could help me!
Thank you in advance.

Upload .RDS file

```
bonemarrow \<- readRDS(file = "C:/Users/merce/Documents/Máster en Bioinformática/TFM/be8db92e-e52c-430c-b3d1-c27b506f8c2e.rds")
str(bonemarrow)
slotNames(bonemarrow)
View(bonemarrow@meta.data)
```

Extract the expression count array from the Seurat object.

In this code, `pbmc.data1@assays$RNA@counts` accesses the expression count matrix inside the Seurat object pbmc.data1. Then, this count array is passed as counts argument to `CreateSeuratObject`

```
counts_matrix <- bonemarrow@assays$RNA@counts
```

Create a new Seurat object using the extracted counts matrix:

```
bonecounts<- CreateSeuratObject(counts = counts_matrix, project = "seuratM")
bonecounts
```

Quality control (QCONTROL):

```
View(bonecounts@meta.data)

#1. PERCENT-MT

# calculate the percentage of mt

# Calculate the percentage of mitochondrial gene expression and assign it to the Seurat object.

# You can get the Ensembl IDs of the rows of the counts matrix.

ensembl_ids \<- rownames(counts_matrix)
```

Load the genomic annotation database for Mus musculus

```
if (!requireNamespace("org.Mm.eg.db", quietly = TRUE)) {
    install.packages("org.Mm.eg.db")
}
library(org.Mm.Mm.eg.db)
```

Get the gene symbols corresponding to the Ensembl IDs

```
gene_symbols \<- select(org.Mm.eg.db, keys=ensembl_ids, columns="SYMBOL", keytype="ENSEMBL")
```

Now, `gene_symbols` contains a mapping between Ensembl IDs and gene symbols.

You can add the gene symbols to your count matrix as row names

```
*rownames(counts_matrix) \<- gene_symbols$SYMBOL*
```

At this step, I found this error:

> rownames(counts_matrix) <- gene_info$external_gene_name
> Error in fixupDN.if.valid(value, x@Dim) :
> length of Dimnames[[1]] (17982) is not equal to Dim[1] (17985)